Reverse Engineering Obsolete Software commands on legacy equipment using RS232
I have attached a RS232 to USB converter and connected SD-100 Verity Monochromator Legacy Equipment(circa 1999 Device). No software available(unable to find and manufacturer does not have) to drive commands to the unit. I know the unit is a self contained with logic and microprocessed controlled and with external(via Rs232)commands will do its own arrangements to scan and send back plottable data from the RS232 port etc. I have randomly sent commands through the Debugging software to send commands and observe the received data. The unit does not respond and not sure if its because its looking for the right commands or a series of commands I am not aware of etc. I am at a lost and would like to be able to use this equipment. Anyone who might have an inkling on the approach or a better idea please let me know... Thanks in advance!!!
